# Magento2 How can I use helper function in config

Tags: magento2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="Pwa_PaywithAmazon::pwa/css/paywithamazon.css"/>
    <block type="core/text" name="pwa.js">
      <action method="setText">
        <text helper="paywithamazon/addPWAJs"/>
      </action>
    </block>
  </head>
  <body>
```

I am calling this in my custom module in magento2 default.xml config

Comment: there is no `core/text` block in magento 2

Comment: then this is not possible

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it will work, but you can try something like this:

```
<block type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="pwa.js" template="[Module]_[Namespace]::some/template.phtml">
    <action method="setText">
       <arguments>
          <argument xsi:type="helper">Helper\ClassName\Here::addPWAJs</argument>
       </arguments>
  </action>
</block>
```

then create the template `[Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/some/template.phtml` with this content:

```
<?php echo $this->getText();?>
```

I haven't tested this, but it looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the equivalent of the **`core/text`** block in Magento 2.
**`Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text`**.

Here's a sample on how to use it in layout xml

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text">
  <action method="setText">
     <argument name="text" xsi:type="string" translate="true">
        <![CDATA[<h4>Information</h4>]]>
     </argument>
 </action>
</block>
```

Furthermore, in your sample you seem to be adding a JS script. I would recommend that you use requirejs instead of explicitly adding it via xml

Answer (score 0):

I try this

```
<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="custom_module/general/enable_in_frontend">
    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_Module::onepage.phtml</argument>
</action>
```